# Clases con atributos recíprocos

Tags: java, atributos

Tengo que crear dos clases, una clase llamada Cliente y otra Pedido.

La primera tiene entre sus atributos un array dinámico de elementos de la clase Pedido que almacena el historial del cliente.

A su vez, La clase Pedido tiene entre sus atributos uno de clase Cliente.

¿Qué debería instanciar primero? ¿Debería tener dos constructores con sobrecarga de Cliente para cuando es cliente nuevo y cuando no? ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo. si no pueden adivinar para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Lo que debes instanciar primero es el cliente, ya que sin cliente no
  existe un pedido.
- no necesitas un constructor con sobrecarga de cliente para cuando es un cliente nuevo, lo que yo hice en este caso fue hacer un constructor sin incluir el ArrayList de los pedidos, pero creé un getter y setter del mismo para cuando necesite agregar pedidos.

Dejo un ejemplo de como lo haría yo

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class Run {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(1, "Agustín", "Gonzales");
            ArrayList<Pedido> pedidos = new ArrayList<>();
            pedidos.add(new Pedido(1, cliente));
            pedidos.add(new Pedido(2, cliente));
            pedidos.add(new Pedido(3, cliente));
            cliente.setPedidos(pedidos);
            
            //Agregar mas pedidos
            cliente.getPedidos().add(new Pedido(4, cliente));
            
            System.out.println(cliente);
            System.out.println("----Lista de pedidos de cliente con id="+ cliente.getId() + "-------");
            cliente.getPedidos().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
            
        }
    }
    
    class Cliente {
        int id;
        String nombre, apellido;
        ArrayList<Pedido> pedidos;
        
        public Cliente(int id, String nombre, String apellido) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;       
        }
        
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
        
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
        
        public String getApellido() {
            return apellido;
        }
        
        public void setApellido(String apellido) {
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }
        
        public ArrayList<Pedido> getPedidos() {
            return pedidos;
        }
        
        public void setPedidos(ArrayList<Pedido> pedidos) {
            this.pedidos = pedidos;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((apellido == null) ? 0 : apellido.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + id;
            result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((pedidos == null) ? 0 : pedidos.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
            if (apellido == null) {
                if (other.apellido != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!apellido.equals(other.apellido))
                return false;
            if (id != other.id)
                return false;
            if (nombre == null) {
                if (other.nombre != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
                return false;
            if (pedidos == null) {
                if (other.pedidos != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!pedidos.equals(other.pedidos))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cliente [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", número de pedidos=" + pedidos.size() + "]";
        }
        
    } 
    
    class Pedido {
        int numeroDePedido;
        Cliente cliente;
        
        public Pedido(int numeroDePedido, Cliente cliente) {
            super();
            this.numeroDePedido = numeroDePedido;
            this.cliente = cliente;
        }
        
        public int getNumeroDePedido() {
            return numeroDePedido;
        }
        
        public void setNumeroDePedido(int numeroDePedido) {
            this.numeroDePedido = numeroDePedido;
        }
        
        public Cliente getCliente() {
            return cliente;
        }
        
        public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
            this.cliente = cliente;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((cliente == null) ? 0 : cliente.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + numeroDePedido;
            return result;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Pedido other = (Pedido) obj;
            if (cliente == null) {
                if (other.cliente != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!cliente.equals(other.cliente))
                return false;
            if (numeroDePedido != other.numeroDePedido)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pedido [numeroDePedido=" + numeroDePedido + ", cliente=" + cliente + "]";
        }
        
    }
```